# How to define cycles in a regex pattern?

Tags: regex

I want to assert that a String contains two identical subStrings.

I tried this regex:     `[A-ZA-Z]{2}`

What I want to detect:

```
AZAZ
CUCU
PIPI
```

But this regex just checks if there are 4 uppercased Letters in a row, so

```
ABCD --> it's good and it shouldn't be
```

I'm really sorry if this is unclear, I don't get how to write the regex to assert repetitions.

Comment: Well what language/flavor are you using ? Basically you need to use a backreference which is not supported in all flavors. In PCRE/PHP you would use `([A-Z]{2})\1`. [See it working](http://regex101.com/r/xR2iD0)

Comment: @HamZa I haven't seen any flavour which doesn't support backreference. Do you know any? It would really be strange to not being able to use backreference in regex.

Comment: @RohitJain I can't come up with one at the moment but after spending so much time on SO, I've bumped into problems where the OP uses a certain system/program where "normal" regex features aren't supported. If my memory doesn't deceive me there was a case where backreference (in a match) wasn't supported in a certain language, but I can't remember which one...

Comment: actually in this specific case, you can just split the string into half and compare them

Comment: Thanks for your help, I needed it for configurating a software using the POSIX standard. I'll come back to you when I know it's working. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: @RohitJain Check out [this page](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html). Seems that POSIX ERE doesn't support them.

Comment: @HamZa Thanks a LOT, it works perfectly as I hoped it would but I don't really understand why (edit: I understood it ;) ). Maybe you could answer the question so that I can validate it? Have a good day.

Comment: As you didn't mention your language I gave an answer valid for Python, just in case. The solution is based in the same idea proposed by HamZa  For some unknown reason the HamZa solution doesn't work in python  2.7 so, in my answer, I used named groups instead of numbered groups.

Comment: @RohitJain If it supports back-references, it is no longer a "regular language". Perl-compatible REs support them, but that is a richer language than regular expressions, per se (as pointe dout, the POSIC regular expressions do not support them).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Python you can do the following:

```
p="((?P<two_chars>[A-Z]{2})(?P=two_chars))"
s="AZAZABCDCUCUPIPI"
re.findall(p, s)
[('AZAZ', 'AZ'), ('CUCU', 'CU'), ('PIPI', 'PI')]
```

and then extract from the list the elements you want. Or you can be faster and do:

```
[k for k,v in re.findall(p,s)]
['AZAZ', 'CUCU', 'PIPI']
```

Hope it helps.